# Migrate tfs server

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I have been searching for a tool to assist with migrating a tfs server and cannot find one! Is it a backup and restore of a database? Has anyone done this before?

My requirements are: we have tfs server A and tfs server B. Both on separate boxes and databases and different domains, as part of consolidation tfs server B will be decommissioned. Moving Code is easy as I can check in a new branch no issues but I don't want to lose all the work items. I don't mind if the work items are assigned to a new single user I just don't want to loose them...

Both 2012. Any ideas thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Permissions Required**

- Servers: Administrators (local Administrators group or equivalent)
- TFS: Team Foundation Administrators and Admin Console Users
- SQL Server: sysadmin
- Analysis server: should be a member of the server administrators group.
- SharePoint: should be a member of the farm administrators group

**Points to be kept in mind**

- The migration activity will require an outage window, depending on the size and number of databases. So plan accordingly and notify the users in advance.
- The TFS commands used in this article should be run from an elevated command prompt, in the below location: 
  *“Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools”*
- Below are the descriptions for the parameters used in the commands that should be run during the migration process.

  - **/DatabaseName**: Specifies the name of the new SQL server that hosts the databases for TFS, in addition to the name of the configuration database.
  - **/SQLInstances**: ServerName1,ServerName2 : Specifies the name of the server that is running SQL Server, in addition to the name of the instance if you want to use an instance other than the default instance. If you are specifying more than one server, you must use a comma to separate multiple pairs of server and instance names.
  - **/AnalysisInstance**: ServerName: Optional. Specifies the name of the server and instance that now hosts SQL Server Analysis Services.
  - **/AnalysisDatabaseName**: DatabaseName: Optional. Specifies the name of the Analysis Services database to be used with TFS if you have more than one such database on the server that you specified with the **/AnalysisInstance** option.

Link to full [process](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2014/05/15/migrating-team-foundation-server-databases/)